# How Can I compile my tex file in PDFLatex, using TexShop on MAC?

Tags: pdf, compiling, texshop, viewers

I am using TexShop (3.97) on a MAC. I have to rewrite an article but I need to compile the tex in PDFLatex. Here is the warning

```
%% This file must be compiled with PDFLaTeX %%
%% Using standard LaTeX will not work!      %%
%%                                          %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The problem is that when I review the composition options there is not something like PDFLatex.

Have anyone has found this problem? I will appreciate much anyone's help.

Comment: Just open a console, switch to the directory in which the file is located, and type `pdflatex <file>.tex`.

Comment: @marmot That will work of course, but a good deal of the LaTeX users on Mac OS X are very reluctant to use the command line… They prefer using a graphical interface like TeXShop (or TeXworks, Texmaker, TeXStudio…).

Comment: @marmot: I would actually recommend `latexmk -pdf <file>` to the new users. As you most probably know, this takes care of `bibtex` and what not.

Answer (score 11):

When TeXShop is active, there is a `Typeset` menu, in which you should mark the `pdftex` option (see also the `Typesetting` panel of TeXShop's Preferences to make this choice permanent).

Once this is done, TeXShop will typeset your documents with PDFLaTeX whenever you select `LaTeX` in the same `Typeset` menu. (Shortcut: `command-shift-L`, or simply `command-t` if the default format chosen in the `Typesetting` Preferences panel is indeed LaTeX.)

Another way to ensure that your document will be typeset by PDFLaTex is to insert the following “magic comment” at the very beginning of this document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
```

This comment is automatically written by TeXShop itself if you choose the relevant option in the `macros/program` menu.

Comment: I agree with your comment but I myself could never imagine compiling LaTeX documents using mouse clicks. +1 for your nice and very accomodating answer. (As you may imagine, for marmots "using a mouse" has two meanings ;-)